# vlite crashes during applying settings phase of rebuild one

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am trying to shrink a RC copy of Windows 7 to fit on a EEE pc 901 by using vLite. Everything seems to work fine until I get to the 'Apply Settings' part of Rebuild One (Ultimate), when vLite abruptly crashes. Could this be an issue with my WAIK installation, or something else? I am downloading a pre-shrunk torrent of Windows 7 but I would feel more comfortable creating my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was an issue with not having access to the temp folder (even though I was running as administrator...)

After looking into this even more (it still didn't work) it seemed like an issue with running vlite itself on windows 7. I copied everything over to an xp box and it worked flawlessly. My eee now runs Windows 7 with about 600 mb to spare on its 4 gig drive.